# Не работает enforceInMethodNames в eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

Добавил в eslintrc такое правило: 
`"rules": {
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "enforceInMethodNames": true,
    "allowAfterThis": true
 }`

Но при проверке eslint всё равно ругается на то, что методы начинаются с " _ "
Хелп[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что вы неправильно указали правило в eslintrc

само правило называется [no-underscore-dangle](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle#disallow-dangling-underscores-in-identifiers-no-underscore-dangle), а enforceInMethodNames - это опции этого правила

и в вашем случае это должно выглядеть так

```
"rules": {
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": ["error", { "enforceInMethodNames": true }]
 }
```